# Actionbar Compat change title textColor

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I am trying to modify the text color of the title of the ActionBarSupport. I have used [ActionBarStyleGenererator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to create a theme with the correct colors and it works well.

While using the light theme, I would like to change the color of the heading to white (in the genererator I cannot set the text color(. For a number of reasons I cannot use the dark actionbar theme. I am so close, just have to get the title to white ;-)

What I am doing wrong here?

```
<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.MyApp" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_myapp</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.MyApp</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyApp.TitleTextStyle</item>  
</style>

 <style name="MyApp.TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Base.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>    
 </style>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Embarrassing. I was not paying attention to the values-v14/-folder (which overrides the vales/) ActionBarStyleGenererator created. Using the android-prefix on the styles in values-v14 it worked:

```
      <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/titleTextStyle</item>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question +1!saved my day!  Hey any reason we have to put --android-prefix -- in v11?

Comment: You are welcome! I cannot say, I had it there and it worked, didn't investigate it further.

Answer (score 14):

The below code worked for me. I hope it will help you tooo.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarCompat</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarCompat" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/titleStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="titleStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.Base.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: That colored my action bar white

Answer (score 3):

Found at [Overflow styling](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/style-androids-overflow-menu-using-this-sanity-saving-workaround/#.)

I've been trying to keep the ActionBar title text color through orientation changes without much luck until I got a clue from the above site.  I applied the Spannable to to the title.  Here's what i do when setting up my ActionBar:

```
    Spannable actionBarTitle = new SpannableString("Action Bar Title");
    actionBarTitle.setSpan(
            new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE),  
            0, 
            actionBarTitle.length(), 
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    mActionBar.setTitle(actionBarTitle);
```

This needs to be executed on orientation change.  I call it from onCreate()...don't know if it works in onConfigurationChange().

Answer (score 0):

@TNR is correct, however you should double check if your layout xml file has not overriden the `android:theme` attribute with a different style.

This usually happens if you have generated layout files